# PhoneGap, iOS 6.1 shows weird alert on launch and hangs at load screen

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2.1

I've built the app in Sencha Touch 2.1.1. It's packaged using PhoneGap. It runs fine as a packaged web app. As soon as the app in the simulator gets past the initial Cordova splash screen I get an alertbox this alert:

[image: iOS Screen Grab]

I'm not sure what's causing this alert. Also, after I click OK it just hangs at the loading screen.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are only seeing this in the iOS simulator, but not on any real devices?

Comment: Is the included cordova/Phonegap JS file version and the one you specified in your index.html file same?

Comment: Haven't tried on a real device, and yes the js file is there. I've actually given up on this. I'm just going to build it native.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this answer can be useful for someone else who find this question searching for a solution. I had the same problem and I solved it: the problem was that the cordova-2.7.0.js file in my iOs project was generated in Android and then copied in the iOs project.

Beware:
the cordova-x.x.x.js file is PLATFORM DEPENDENT. So you have to include the right one.