# Android Phonegap App gives weird alerts in iOs app

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

I have build on Phonegap app and it gives me error as shown in screenshot.
[image: This is alert error i am getting]

I found one reply on URL : [PhoneGap, iOS 6.1 shows weird alert on launch and hangs at load screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302216/phonegap-ios-6-1-shows-weird-alert-on-launch-and-hangs-at-load-screen) .

But, I am not sure how to build unique cordova.js file for ios ?

Should i create separate project in mac and build it or project created on windows pc will work ?

Comment: you are using the android cordova.js on an ios project, they are different

Comment: where can i find that cordova.js file for ios project ?

Comment: you don't have to search it, it's automatically generated and copied to it's place when you add ios platform to your project. I think you are doing things in the wrong way, read the cordova docs and learn how to work with it